# how to display a players final time in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, timer

I have created a memory card matching game where a player has to match up 30 cards on the screen. There is a timer on the screen which goes up by 1 every second. I want it so once the player has matched up all 15 pairs, the game ends and the players time, so how long they took to complete it is displayed in another screen which says - "Your Time was ..." .

So far i have coded everything , i have a timer that works perfectly fine and all the matching aspects is good. However, once the game ends and the text is displayed on the final winning screen, the Timer is still going and so i cant get the players final time. For example, if the player took 60 seconds to complete all pairs it should say "Your Time was 60 seconds!!". However even after the game is ended the timer is still going. Here is my code so far:

```
# build a guessing game!
import random
import pygame


global options_list, spaces, used, new_board, first_guess, second_guess, first_guess_num, second_guess_num, score, matches, game_over, rows, cols, correct, time
pygame.init()

# game variables and constants
screen_width = 600
screen_height = 600
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
orange = (255,97,3)
turquoise = (0, 206, 209)
green = (0, 255, 0)
fps = 60
timer = pygame.time.Clock()
rows = 5
cols = 6
correct = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,], 
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

options_list = []
spaces = []
used = []
new_board = True
first_guess = False
second_guess = False
#Guess is assigned an index value. Checks what number is clicked
first_guess_num = 0
second_guess_num = 0
score = 0
matches = 0
game_over = False
cards_left_covered = 0
#timer start time
start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
time = 0

# create screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width, screen_height])
pygame.display.set_caption('Memory Game!')
#sets fonts
large_font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 56)
small_font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 26)



def generate_board():
    global options_list, spaces, used
    for item in range(rows * cols // 2):
        options_list.append(item)
        
# goes through list of options between 1-24. Guarantees that only 2 cards can be selected
    for item in range(rows * cols):
        card = options_list[random.randint(0, len(options_list) - 1)]
        spaces.append(card)
        if card in used:
            used.remove(card)
            options_list.remove(card)
        else:
            used.append(card)

#Sets background colours and shapes
def draw_backgrounds():
    global start_time, time
    
    top_menu = pygame.draw.rect(screen, orange, [0, 0, screen_width, 75])
    score_text = small_font.render(f'Player 1 score :  {score}', True, white)
    screen.blit(score_text, (20, 20))
    
    board_space = pygame.draw.rect(screen, turquoise, [0, 100, screen_width, screen_height - 200], 0)
    
    bottom_menu = pygame.draw.rect(screen, orange, [0, screen_height - 100, screen_width, 100], 0)
    time = 0 + int((pygame.time.get_ticks() + start_time) / 1000)
    time_text = small_font.render(f'Your time: {time}', True, white)
    screen.blit(time_text, (20, 550))
    
    



def draw_cards():
    global rows, columns, correct
    card_list = []
    for i in range(cols):
        for j in range(rows):
            
            #draws the cards and sets their size and position
            card = pygame.draw.rect(screen, orange,[i * 85 + 48, j *78 + 110, 61, 65], 0, 4)
            card_list.append(card)
            ## randomly adds numbers onto the cards. to make sure that the black numbers dont populate instantly when game is created 
            '''card_text = small_font.render(f'{spaces[i * rows + j]}', True, black)
            screen.blit(card_text, (i * 75 + 18, j * 65 + 120))'''

    for r in range(rows):
        for c in range(cols):
            if correct[r][c] == 1:
                #creates green border around cards when match is made
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, green, [c * 85 + 48, r * 78 + 110, 61, 65], 3, 4)
                card_text = small_font.render(f'{spaces[c * rows + r]}', True, black)
                screen.blit(card_text, (c * 85 + 55, r * 78 + 125))

    return card_list


def check_guesses(first, second):
    global spaces, correct, score, matches
    if spaces[first] == spaces[second]:
        
        #floor division
        col1 = first // rows
        col2 = second // rows
        row1 = first - (first // rows * rows)
        row2 = second - (second // rows * rows)

        #checks for match and score incremented by 1
        if correct[row1][col1] == 0 and correct[row2][col2] == 0:
            correct[row1][col1] = 1
            correct[row2][col2] = 1
            score += 1
            matches += 1


running = True
while running:
    timer.tick(fps)
    screen.fill(turquoise)
    if new_board:
        generate_board()
        new_board = False

    draw_backgrounds()
    board = draw_cards()

    if first_guess and second_guess:
        check_guesses(first_guess_num, second_guess_num)
        
        ##delays code for miliseconds to see second guess
        pygame.time.delay(1000)
        first_guess = False
        second_guess = False

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            for i in range(len(board)):
                button = board[i]
                
            #can guess as long as it's not game over
                if not game_over:
                 if button.collidepoint(event.pos) and not first_guess:
                    first_guess = True
                    first_guess_num = i
                    
        ##ensures that the same card cannot be clicked twice
                if button.collidepoint(event.pos) and not second_guess and first_guess and i != first_guess_num:
                    second_guess = True
                    second_guess_num = i
                    

#Checks for game over
    if matches == rows * cols // 2:
        game_over = True
        winner = pygame.draw.rect(screen, turquoise,[0, 0, 600, 600])
        winner_text = large_font.render(f'YOUR TIME WAS {end_time} !!', True, orange)
        screen.blit(winner_text, (70, screen_height - 350))
        

#allows card to be flipped to show number
    if first_guess:
        card_text = small_font.render(f'{spaces[first_guess_num]}', True, black)
        location = (first_guess_num // rows * 85 + 55, (first_guess_num - (first_guess_num // rows * rows)) * 78 + 125)
        screen.blit(card_text, (location))
        
    if second_guess:
        card_text = small_font.render(f'{spaces[second_guess_num]}', True, black)
        location = (second_guess_num // rows * 85 + 55, (second_guess_num - (second_guess_num // rows * rows)) * 78 + 125)
        screen.blit(card_text, (location))

    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set `end_time` when the game state changes to `game_over`:

```py
while running:
    # [...]

    if matches == rows * cols // 2:
       
        if not game_over:
            end_time = time
        game_over = True

        winner = pygame.draw.rect(screen, turquoise,[0, 0, 600, 600])
        winner_text = large_font.render(f'YOUR TIME WAS {end_time} !!', True, orange)
        screen.blit(winner_text, (70, screen_height - 350))
```